# Issue with Relation Annotation (rel.manual) in Spacy's Prodigy tool

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, spacy

I am trying to build a relation extraction model via spacy's prodigy tool.

NOTE: ner.manual, ner.correct, rel.manual are all recipes provided by prodigy.

1. (ner.manual, ner.correct) The first step involved annotating and training a NER model that can predict entities (this step is done and model is obtained)
2. The next step involved annotating the relations between the entities. Now, this step could be done int wo different method.

   i. Label the entities and relations all from scratch

   ii. Use the trained NER model to predict the entities in the UI tool and make corrections to it if needed (similar to ner.correct) and label the relations between the entities

The issue I am now facing is, whenever I use the trained model in the recipe's loop (rel.manual), there is no entities predicted.

Could someone help me with this??

PS: There is no trailing whitespaces issue, i cross-verified it

Comment: How to load in data that has been pre-annotated with entity spans in Prodigy’s format and annotate relations between them, or use a pre-trained model to suggest entities for me?